# Extract Facebook SDK v7.9.4 from Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to integrate Trial Period in my game(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gameroom/premium), but the FB.Arcade API is only available in SDK version 7.9.4. The only way to get this version is to download Unity with integrated Facebook, but my current version of unity (5.5.0f3) is bugged and it makes my game crash.

Upgrading to latest versions(5.6) only making things worse.

So can someone tell me how to extract Facebook SDK v7.9.4 Gameroom from Unity, or how to get 5.5.0p3 version with FB Gameroom Build target.

Comment: You are looking for a place to download Facebook SDK v7.9.4 Unity plugin?

Comment: Yes, something like this. I want to use Facebook SDK in Unity which doesn't have build-in Facebook support.